# Web Worker blob IE11 SCRIPT0 Expected ';' error for only a single user

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob, internet-explorer-11, web-worker

I have an Javascript web application which users a worker to do some time consuming data transposition. I create the worker using a blob, as show in code below.

I have my worker function in a variable:

```
var workerCode = function(){
   var transposeRules = function(...){
      //Heavy processing code here
   }

   onmessage = function(event) {  
        transposeRules(...);
  };
}
```

And I use the function to create a blob, and pass the blobURL into a new worker as below:

```
var blob = new Blob(['(' + workerCode.toString() + ')();'], {type: 'text/javascript'});
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var worker = new Worker(blobURL); // Create the worker as usual
```

Note that in the non-dev environments, all the code is minified.

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and even in IE11 for MOST users, but there is ONE user of the application (one of the main ones actually....) who gets the below error:

```
SCRIPT0: expected ';' 
Failed to open blob:B65071CD-93A4-4340-A74B-723F9D9E1598
```

I have no idea what the cause of this is. I've seen similar threads where someone had this expected ';' error but he had a dodgy character in the function - I have copied the blob code and can't see anything wrong with it - besides, it works for 99% of the users, all except one.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this? Perhaps it's some IE11 setting I'm unaware of or something? Thanks!

Comment: With non way for us to test the problem, this question has no reason to even exist.

Comment: Someone might have come across the same problem and so can give their advice

Comment: I am getting the same error did find any solution ?!